# Can I skip implementing tessellation shader in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader, tessellation

Yesterday,I bought a book about OpenGL 4.5 and the thing is that the project I am now working on doesn't require any tessellation features in order to pass. So I want to skip implementing tessellation shader among many other stages of OpenGL pipelines. Is it okay to skip it or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yeah, it's not a mandatory stage

Comment: Thanks for replying and there is one more thing to ask. If that is not mandatory, how can I pass some primitives directly from vertex shader to geometry shader? From what I've learned from the book I'm reading, the sequence of shader is as follow. Vertex -> Tess -> Geometry -> Rasterization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vertex Shader is the only mandatory shader. Geometry, Tessellation Control, Tessellation Evaluation and Fragment Shaders are all optional. Though in most cases you don't want the Fragment shader to be optional.

If you do use Tessellation, the TCS is optional (you can define OpenGL sided defaults) and only the TES is absolutely necessary. But there is no flag or anything to activate Tessellation, OpenGL will "think" you're using Tessellation if you compile a TES along with the other shaders.

So yes, you can skip Tessellation if you want to. Check this for more info [OpenGL tessellation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation)